# SublimeText - sort json list alphabetically

Tags: sorting, sublimetext2, alphabetical

I have a json formated list of countries and their ISO codes:

```
.
.
{"cod":"NC", "nombre":"Nueva Caledonia"},   
{"cod":"NE", "nombre":"Níger"}, 
{"cod":"NF", "nombre":"Islas Norkfolk"},    
{"cod":"NG", "nombre":"Nigeria"},   
{"cod":"NI", "nombre":"Nicaragua"}, 
{"cod":"NL", "nombre":"Países Bajos"},      
.
.
```

The list is sorted alphabetically but by the ISO code and not by the name. Is there any way to sort this list by name using sublime text or any other editor ?

Thanks

Comment: dump it in excel, split, sort, join

Comment: Genius !! already done. I didn't thought on that possibility. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but no accepted answer. https://jsoneditoronline.org has a function to do this.

Click the "sort" button and it will let you choose the property to sort on the "field" key.

[image: JSON Editor Online - Sort elements]

Answer (score 1):

If you split "cod" and "nombre" then you will be able to use SublimeText functional: Select text, Edit -> Sort Lines or press F5

Comment: In the recent version, the hot key is F9.